# How to backUp a copy of SQLite DB to SkyDrive in Win8

Tags: winrt-xaml

Understand that If user Uninstall WinRT App, the SQLite Database in it will be erased or gone. So, it is possible to make a copy of the Database and How to do it?

1) can Upload to SkyDrive ?

2)Since Tablet has USB slot, can make a copy to the USB-Thumb Drive?

Your help on this is much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this nice blog post for how to do backup of database to SkyDrive.

[How to Integrate SkyDrive Backup in Windows 8 App?](http://www.coderewind.com/2012/08/how-to-integrate-skydrive-backup-in-windows-8-app/)

For copy pasting to USB drive, you need to request user to open `FolderPicker` and select USB drive as location, then you will have `StorageFolder` object. So you can copy the SQLite file.